# Using Concern in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a concern

app/models/concerns/map_scope.rb

```
module MapScope
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    def map_scope(string_to_map)
      #some mapping logic happens here
      return string_to_map
    end

  end
end
```

app/views/customers/index.html.erb

```
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Scope</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= customer.id %></td>
                  <td>
                    <%= map_scope(customer.scope_name) %>
                  </td>

                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

I can't get the below line to work, as I need to map each row in the table

```
<%= map_scope(customer.scope_name) %>
```

Errors on: `undefined method map_scope' for #<#< Class..`

How do I make the map_scope function available to use in the views without using the application controller?

Comment: If you want to use the method in the views, why not to use a helper?

Comment: What do you think model concerns are and what problem they solve? Why not use a view helper?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your method? why do you need it if you just return the argument without doing anything with it?

Comment: I didn't want to clutter the application_controller with a method, so I figured a concern would be better since I only need it in some controllers. You guys think it should still be a helper method?

Comment: @SebastianPalma, sorry, it does some mapping logic, I just didn't include it for brevity

Comment: Well, sounds like I need to use app/helpers/application_helper.rb and just put the method in there. If anyone cares to make it an answer, I'll accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do anything before showing an attribute, then you can keep using your model concern, but at the moment of accessing that method:

```
# model
class Customer
  include MapScope
end

# model/concern
module MapScope
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def map_scope
      foo
    end
  end
end

# view
<td>
  <%= customer.map_scope %> # foo
</td>
```

If you want to use a helper (in ApplicationHelper):

```
# helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def map_scope(string_to_map)
    foo
  end
end

# view
<td>
  <%= map_scope(customer.scope_name) %> # foo
</td>
```

If you want to use a decorator ([`drapergem/draper`](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)):

```
# app/decorators/customer_decorator.rb
class CustomerDecorator < Drapper::Decorator
  include Draper::LazyHelpers

  def map_scope
    # the customer object is "object" within the decorator classes.
    # object.scope_name 
    foo
  end
end

# view
<td>
  <%= customer.map_scope %> # foo
</td>
```

Comment: Yeah, the helper was probably the way to go. Are you sure your first suggestion works through the concern?

Comment: Doesn't it? the model concern one? it should, really I didn't test it :3

Comment: I'm getting an undefined method, although I may be doing something wrong.. I think that would work in a controller but not a view. The helper works though in the view

Comment: Yes it does, if you're referring to an specific object it works as an attribute of it, an instance method on the class you're working on.